# Django query to get User's favorite posts?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm a little confused by the Django lingo. So I have 3 models: Post, UserProfile(User), Favorite. Favorite keeps track of which Posts a User has favorited.

Post--->Favorite<---User/UserProfile

Favorite model:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    def get_favorites(self):
        if self.user:
            return self.user.favorite_set.all()
```

In my post_list view I pass all Posts to my template, and in the template I have a for loop that displays all Posts.

```
{% for post in post_list %}
<hr/>
<div id=”post_{{ post.id }}”>
    {% include 'posts/_post.html' %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in that for loop I would like to put a logic that will display "Favorited!" if the logged-in User has favorited the Post. I think the conventional SQL is something like this:

```
SELECT favorite.post FROM favorite WHERE favorite.user = user.id
```

So that in the template loop I can do

```
{% if post in the.above.SQL.query%}Favorited!{% endif %}
```

Now I just can't translate that to Django lingo for some reason. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thing to recognise is that your `Favorite` model is actually the through table of a many-to-many relationship between Post and User. Django can actually manage that automatically if you declare a ManyToManyField somewhere. Personally, I would do that on UserProfile - so the relationship actually becomes one between Post and UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='favorited_by')
```

Now you don't need your `get_favorites` method, as it is available via `userprofile.favorites.all()`. You *could* just use this as-is in the template:

```
{% if post in userprofile.favorites.all %}Favorited!{% endif %}
```

but this will end up being extremely inefficient, as you'll be doing the same identical query for each post in your list of posts. So, use the `{% with %}` tag to get the favorites once before the loop:

```
{% with userprofile.favorites.all as favorite_posts %}
  {% for post in post_list %}
    {% if post in favorite_posts %}Favorited{% endif %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Worked like a magical charm. I've never used ManyToMany, never paid much attention to it. Now I know! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

While Daniel makes good point, i'll just post the query you wanted :)

```
Post.objects.filter(favorite__user=user)
```

Comment: Can someone point to django Documentation to such a usage. I thought you could only move across tables starting at a tables foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Since its many to many relationships,
`fav_post = user.favourite.all()` you can pass this `fav_post` to context. Then in the template, you will need to iterate that context key