# How To Save A User's Favorite Posts in Django

Tags: python, django

So, i'm trying to allow a user to favorite a post (in my case Deals), which will later be displayed on their profile page.

**UPDATED --The problem I'm having--when the form to save a favorite is submitted, the favorite is not saving in database.

I got my initial inspiration from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674968/django-query-to-get-users-favorite-posts)

So i added a 'favorites' field to my User model with a Many to Many relationship on my Deal model...like so:

`favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Deal, related_name='favorited_by')`

My html template where a user can favorite a 'Deal' looks like this:

```
<form id="favorite{{deal_detail.id}}" method="POST" action="{% url 'deals:favorite' deal_detail.id %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Add Deal to Favorites" />
```

My url for favorites is this:

`url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/favorite', favorite, name='favorite')`

this is the view for 'deal_detail' and 'favorite'

```
def deal_by_detail(request, slug):
    deal_detail = Deal.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'deals/deal_detail.html', {'deal_detail': deal_detail})


def favorite(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deal = Deal.objects.get(pk=pk)
        deal.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Deal Favorited.')
        return redirect('home')
```

and here are my full User and Deals models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email has already been registered."})
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Deal, related_name='favorited_by', null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Deal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer)
    image = VersatileImageField('deal image',
                               upload_to=deal_upload_path,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    date_expires = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    secondary_price = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='')
    likes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: maybe all are appearing (just for selection) but the selected ones are correct. Check with a queryset.

Comment: What was your actual problem?

Comment: ok, so i checked with queryset and it doesn't appear that a favorite is being saved to the database when form is submitted.  In the admin, i am able actually able to select a favorite for a specific user...so issue is with my form --not sure if you see any issues there?

Comment: it must be because i'm saving deal object in `favorite` view...where the 'favorites' field is in my User model...i'll copy full models above

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i'm not sure if this is the perfect way to do this, but it appears to be working.  I created a variable 'favorite' to grab the selected item and then then saved in the user object.

```
def favorite(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        favorite = Deal.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user = request.user
        user.favorites.add(favorite)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Deal Favorited.')
        return redirect('home')
```